# How to get current windows user on ASP.Net 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get current windows user in new ASP.Net 5.

This returns correctly when run from Visual Studio, when I deploy it to the server it returns app pool identity:

```
string name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

This returns empty string:

```
string name = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
```

This have been dropped in bew ASP version:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not specified where you want to obtain this information, but from within a Controller it is available as `User.Identity.Name`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = $"Hello, {User.Identity.Name}";
    return View();
}
```

This results in "Hello, Desktop-PC\User".  You can also do this within a View.

Answer (score 1):

What is the authentication mode are you using?

If you have following settings

- Authentication Mode = Windows
- Impersonation in application
- Anonymous access disabled on IIS website

Then your code below should give "name" as domain\WinAccount Name

```
string name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: Howe do I set Impersonation in ASP.Net 5?

Answer (score 0):

You get the app pool identity because that is the account with which your process executes. If you want the identity of the user making the call you need to use impersonation.

You can either add `<identity impersonate="true" />` to web.config or you can avoid direct editing of web.config by using IIS Manager; select your web site, click Authentication and enable ASP.NET Impersonation.

Comment: Web.config doesn't exist in ASP.Net 5 and I don't see Impersonation option in IIS manager